# A couple of wrinkles were ironed out

Tags: meaning

What does it mean exactly when somebody says:

> A couple of wrinkles were ironed out.

Comment: [Iron out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/iron+out) - To ease a problem; to smooth out a problem. It also means to use a flatiron to make cloth flat or smooth. *source: [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com)*

Comment: Context please. Could be used figuratively or literally. What *do you think*?

Comment: @Stephie I really cant give any context; it turned up in a daily conversation.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you need to provide more of your context to get a definite answer.

*Iron out the wrinkles* Literally means *to remove wrinkles from something, especially a piece of fabric, using a flatiron* as in

> Your new dress shirt is all rumpled! You'll need to iron out the wrinkles before you go to the ceremony this evening.

Also it can bear an idiomatic sense which is informal and means *to fix the small problems in something* as in

> We still have to iron out a few more wrinkles in the schedule.

So your sentence can mean idiomatically *a couple of problems were fixed or taken care of* Or literally *the creases were smoothed/removed by ironing a piece of clothes*.